# CSS | Cursor changes back to normal with "cursor: url('cursor.png'), url('cursor.ico'), move !important;"

Tags: html, css, cursors

I want to change the cursor to a round circle with CSS. In order to do I've used the following line of code:

```
* {
   cursor: url('cursor.png'), url('cursor.ico'), move !important;
}
```

It is working fine but there is a problem that I couldn't figure out: the cursor switches back to default when the cursor doesn't move for longer than 1 second (it goes back to normal).  Why is that, and what can I do about it?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jusugahixa/2/edit?html,css,output — I can't reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, seems to be a Mac bug or something went away when I did a restart. It's not always the code!

Thanks for the replies!